# How to find repeated word in a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `codecodecodecodecode......` I need to find a repeated word in that string.

I found a way but the regular expression always returns half of the repeated part I want.

```
^(.*)\1+$
```

[image]

at the group(1) I want to see just "code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is greedy, it will first match till the end of the line, and will then backtrack until it can repeat 1 or more times till the end of the string, and for an evenly divided part like this of 4 words, you can capture 2 words and match the same 2 words with the backreference `\1`

If you have 5 words like `codecodecodecodecode` as in your example there will be a single group, as the only repetition it can do until the end of the string is 5 repetitions.

The quantifier should be non greedy (and repeat 1+ times to not match an empty string) to match as least as possible characters that can be repeated to the right till the end of the string.

```
^(.+?)\1+$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9IKUL/1)

Comment: thank you for explanation and solution

Comment: @MehmetAliGÜNDÜZ That is correct, as the current pattern asserts the end of the string using `$` In that case you can use `^(.+?)\1+` See https://regex101.com/r/LtRdJM/1